# What's the point of this plan in Flash season 2 finale?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

**Potential spoiler for people who hasn 't seen The Flash Season 2 finale!**

In the Season 2 finale, the team (almost all the team) have a plan to beat Zoom, which basically consists in sending him back to Earth 2.

But what's exactly the point of sending him back to Earth 2, knowing that he is able to open breaches between worlds? Therefore he can go back to Earth 1 whenever he wants

> and he did so a few minutes later!

Is it just the silliest plan ever?

Comment: I'm fairly certain they were mostly concerned with delaying him long enough to destroy the machine. Or I may just be trying to justify bad writing here.

Answer (score 1):

The idea was to close the breaches once and for all (again). That's what they all agreed upon, no matter what happens they all agreed to it.

Comment: yeah but unless they closed the breaches *immediately* after sending Zoom through, then Zoom could just pop right back over.  They did nothing to prevent him from doing so, as far as I could see.  Yet even without Wally/Barry's interference in the plan, they took the time to head back to Star Labs and then to (presumably) get to work closing them.  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can't Zoom open a new breach anyway?

Comment: It could be that Zoom can only do that so long as at least one other breach is already open. If all of them are closed, then he can't make a breach. That'd explain why he was waiting around doing nothing when Cisco opened the first portal (after they closed them all the first time). The complication here is that he had gained Barry's speed, so maybe the ability to open breaches came from that theft.

Comment: It was my understanding that they did indeed close the breaches once Zoom (along with Joe) went through.  After Cisco's vibe session they re-opened one to let Zoom come back.